# Write angularjs view code inside sweetalert

Tags: angularjs, sweetalert

I want to render angularjs code inside a sweet alert, 
example

```
$scope.someVar = 'test';

swal("Title", "{ someVar }", "success")
```

How can I achieve that ?

Comment: I am sorry this in not answering my question in any case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to wrap your someVar in brackets, but you do need to call it by $scope.someVar (we're in javascript!). So an example would be:

```
sweetAlert({
            title: $scope.someTitle,
            text: $scope.someVar,
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please look at [$interpolate service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interpolate)

[Check example](http://plnkr.co/edit/Ssg3nSAwdtAztx79dLGb?p=preview):

```
swal("Title", $interpolate("{{someVar}}")($scope), "success");
```